# My code returns one correct review and NULL instead of the other reviews

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrape

This is the code

```
import scrapy
   

class YelpscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yelpscrape'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yelp.com/biz/beretta-san-francisco?osq=Restaurants']

    def parse(self, response):

        for review in response.css('ul.undefined.list__373c0__3GI_T'):
            item = {
                
                'review': review.css('p.comment__373c0__1M-px.css-n6i4z7 span').get()
            }
            
            yield item
```

This is what it returns

```
[
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": "Correct review"},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null},
{"review": null}
]
```

I just can't quite understand what to change so it returns all correctly. I played around and got 18 copies of the same review, which is not what I'm looking for as well. Could you guys help me on this one?

Comment: When retrieving the review: value pair, the value is based on the "p.comment__373c0__1M-px.css-n6i4z7 span" css selector. The issue might be due to different reviews having different css values instead of the one you input. The only review having that value is the 9th, the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the page in your browser, and click through the pages of reviews while logging your browser's network traffic, you'll see an XHR HTTP GET request being made to a REST API every time you click to view another page of reviews. The response of the API is JSON, which contains information for ten reviews at a time. All you have to do is imitate that request - to get more reviews, you'll have to make multiple requests to the same API endpoint, but with different query-string parameters (the `"start"` key-value pair in the `params` dictionary starts at `"0"`, then goes up to `"10"`, `"20"`, etc.):

```
def get_reviews(restaurant_id):
    import requests

    url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/{}/review_feed".format(restaurant_id)

    params = {
        "rl": "en",
        "q": "",
        "sort_by": "relevance_desc",
        "start": "0"
    }

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "x-requested-by-react": "true",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    yield from (review["comment"]["text"] for review in response.json()["reviews"])
    

def main():

    for review in get_reviews("4KfQnlcSu4bbTqnvGdGptw"):
        print(review, "\n")
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: So I can't get all the reviews via a regular loop and need to check the API and work with what it gives me, right?

Comment: Yup, I would use a loop. The API's response even contains the total number of reviews, so you could use that to figure out how many iterations you need.